# Flask and SQLAlchemy's Column type

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a Flask app with SQLAlchemy.
In Odoo ORM, we have a column or a field named 'Selection'.
I wanna do something great like this into SQLAlchemy:

```
STATUS = [('admin','Admin'),('guest','Guest')]
status = db.Column(db.Selection, selection=STATUS)
```

With Odoo's ORM:

```
status = fields.Selection(STATUS, default='guest')
```

I don't wanna create a new Model to store these : 'admin','guest','superadmin'.
Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLAlchemy enum. Check SQLAlchemy 1.3 Documentation here: [class sqlalchemy.types.Enum(*enums, **kw)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum)

```
class Status(enum.Enum):
    ADMIN = "admin"
    GUEST = "guest"

class MyTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    status = db.Column(db.Enum(Status), default=Status.GUEST)
```

Comment: I found the best way to do it with ChoiceType.  https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#choice-type